# How to scroll popup dialog in instagram and scrape followers?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape followers from an account. I did everything but I am stuck is scrolling the popup dialog. When I click the followers button a popup comes. Then I have to scroll down to the end and scrape all the followers name.

Here is my code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
username_field = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((
    By.XPATH, "//input[@name='username']"
)))
time.sleep(2)
password_field = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((
    By.XPATH, "//input[@name='password']"
)))

time.sleep(2)

username_field.clear()
password_field.clear()
username_field.send_keys("#######")
password_field.send_keys("#########")

time.sleep(2)
login = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((
    By.XPATH,
    "/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/section[1]/main[1]/article[1]/div["
    "2]/div[1]/div[2]/form[1]/div[1]/div[3]/button[1] "
))).click()

search = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((
    By.CSS_SELECTOR, "body > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > "
                     "div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > "
                     "div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > "
                     "div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) "
)))
search.click()


search_field = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((
    By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='Search']"
)))

search_field.send_keys("dunn")

dunn = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((
    By.XPATH,
    "//a[@href='/dunn/']//div[@class='x9f619 xjbqb8w x78zum5 x168nmei x13lgxp2 x5pf9jr xo71vjh xxbr6pl xbbxn1n xwib8y2 x1y1aw1k x1uhb9sk x1plvlek xryxfnj x1c4vz4f x2lah0s xdt5ytf xqjyukv x1qjc9v5 x1oa3qoh x1nhvcw1']//div[@class='x9f619 x1n2onr6 x1ja2u2z x1qjc9v5 x78zum5 xdt5ytf x1iyjqo2 xl56j7k xeuugli']//div[@class='x9f619 x1n2onr6 x1ja2u2z x78zum5 x2lah0s x1qughib x6s0dn4 xozqiw3 x1q0g3np']//div[@class='x9f619 x1n2onr6 x1ja2u2z x78zum5 x1iyjqo2 xs83m0k xeuugli x1qughib x6s0dn4 x1a02dak x1q0g3np xdl72j9']//div[@class='x9f619 x1n2onr6 x1ja2u2z x78zum5 xdt5ytf x2lah0s x193iq5w xeuugli x1iyjqo2']//div[@class='x9f619 xjbqb8w x78zum5 x168nmei x13lgxp2 x5pf9jr xo71vjh x1uhb9sk x1plvlek xryxfnj x1iyjqo2 x2lwn1j xeuugli xdt5ytf xqjyukv x1cy8zhl x1oa3qoh x1nhvcw1']//span[@class='x1lliihq x1plvlek xryxfnj x1n2onr6 x193iq5w xeuugli x1fj9vlw x13faqbe x1vvkbs x1s928wv xhkezso x1gmr53x x1cpjm7i x1fgarty x1943h6x x1i0vuye xvs91rp x1s688f x5n08af x10wh9bi x1wdrske x8viiok x18hxmgj']//span[@class='x1lliihq x193iq5w x6ikm8r x10wlt62 xlyipyv xuxw1ft']//div[@class='x9f619 xjbqb8w x78zum5 x168nmei x13lgxp2 x5pf9jr xo71vjh x1uhb9sk x1plvlek xryxfnj x1c4vz4f x2lah0s x1q0g3np xqjyukv x6s0dn4 x1oa3qoh x1nhvcw1']"
)))

dunn.click()

follower_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((
    By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href='/dunn/followers/']"
)))

follower_button.click()
print("Followers Found. Scraping followers")


followers = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href, '/')]")

# //div[contains(text(),'amirex1183')]

# Getting url from href attribute
users = set()
for i in followers:
    if i.get_attribute('href'):
        users.add(i.get_attribute('href').split("/")[3])
    else:
        continue
print("Info Saving........")
print("Done scraping data..")

with open('followers.txt', 'a') as file:
    file.write('\n'.join(users) + "\n")

time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```

In this code everything is working but I can't scroll down the popup dialog and can't scrape the followers.

Is there any better solution for this? I am using python selenium for this.

and my output is coming like this:

```
directory
direct
?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.penguinrandomhouse.com%2Fbooks%2F653309%2Fburn-rate-by-andy-dunn%2F&e=AT0q19otIXi8YQbFLmJagY77-HIzx8jRmBBJeB_70HFbVroT2vvlt_3bCGViJSlXax6_guJxblN04igYdsKpGv032Z34YcJ1wOTGjM8
legal
docs
bonobos
web
reels
dunn
explore
technologies
blog
?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fhelp%2Finstagram%2F261704639352628&e=AT1mG5QKzJ58e8F_R2ZuWtWjNamsWjJzDoJlDbP2lHyZT6rCFeNsd6ggE1869Ev5eJUsdd1dN3GSbJukxV6K11Sqxs4nTCgszP4gmqLNRyFdkkjK5IpZiUPEoHSFzQccZSxwYqsGLJEJIVBXfeuq4g
about
dangahmed38
p
```

Comment: have you tried instaloder ? this module already implements what you are trying to achieve here .

Comment: no I haven't tried it yet @AkashTripathi

Comment: https://github.com/instaloader/instaloader